# How to work With multiple Spinners?

Tags: android

I need to work with 3 Spinners, meaning that if one item from the Spinner number 1 is selected, then the spinner number 2 will become visible, and if another item from the Spinner number 1 is selected, then the Spinner number 3 will become visible, and the number 2 invisible, in order to do this, do i need to work with 3 ArrayAdapter, one per each?? or can i work with one ArrayAdapter?  Any help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayAdapter means 'An adapter for an array of elements`. Not 'An array of adapters'. If you want to work with 3 spinners, you will have to use 3 adapters.

```
final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); // invisible by default
final Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); // invisible by default

spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
spinner3.setAdapter(adapter3);

spinner1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(position == 0) {
            spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if(position == 1) {
            spinner3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});  //like this for all the three
```

Comment: Very thanks. i just made it.......and then i realized that my question was not worth: this is my code. String time= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                if(time.contains("Others")){
                    mOthers.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    mOthers.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                }
                if(time.contains("Breakfast")){
            }

Comment: yeah the answer helped me but still i don't know why i got a -1 .....well..thanks!

Comment: That's ok. Different ppl see different problems with different complexities. I see it as a valid one. So +1.

Answer (score 0):

An Adapter object acts as a bridge between an AdapterView and the underlying data for that view.

If you want to show same data to all of the three Spinners, Then you can use one adapter for the spinners else you need to create separate adapter for each.